Get MAX date from SQLite DB using R
I'm trying to get the MAX(date) from a column using RSQLite. I'm not sure where the issue is, in the db or in R.
library(RSQLite)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <-  tibble(date_col = whole_seq <- seq(ymd("2024-08-01"), ymd("2024-08-24"), by = "day"))

sql_db <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "", extended_types = TRUE)

dbWriteTable(sql_db, "df", df)

dbSendQuery(sql_db, "SELECT MAX(date_col) FROM df") %>% dbFetch()
dbSendQuery(sql_db, "SELECT DATE(MAX(date_col)) FROM df") %>% dbFetch()
dbSendQuery(sql_db, "SELECT MAX(DATE(date_col)) FROM df") %>% dbFetch()


Are you storing your dates in one of the listed formats? https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html#time_values

In R, dates are coded as consecutive integers starting in 1970-01-01. Some functions forget the "Date" class attribute and return the corresponding number. In that case, you have to coerce back to a real date class.
library(RSQLite)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <-  tibble(date_col = whole_seq <- seq(ymd("2024-08-01"), ymd("2024-08-24"), by = "day"))

sql_db <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "", extended_types = TRUE)

dbWriteTable(sql_db, "df", df)

dbSendQuery(sql_db, "SELECT MAX(date_col) FROM df") %>% 
  dbFetch() %>% 
  mutate(max_date = as.Date(`MAX(date_col)`, origin = "1970-01-01"))
#>   MAX(date_col)   max_date
#> 1         19959 2024-08-24

Created on 2024-09-30 with reprex v2.1.0

extended_types does not appear to be fully implemented.  See https://github.com/r-dbi/RSQLite/issues/351 and issues referenced there.
1) You will have to convert the output yourself.
library(RSQLite)

DF <- data.frame(d = as.Date("2000-01-01") + 0:3)
con <- dbConnect(SQLite())
dbWriteTable(con, "DF", DF)

dbGetQuery(con, "select max(d) as maxd from DF") |>
  transform(maxd = .Date(maxd))
##         maxd
## 1 2000-01-04

dbDisconnect()

2) Alternately if sqldf is applicable (which would be the case if you are using R data frames as the input rather than an external database) then it has a built in heuristic that will do (1) for you if the output column name is the same as the input column name.  sqldf will automatically upload any tables it sees in the SQL statement so in this case it will automatically upload DF and it will notice that column d in the output has a different class than column d in the input and convert it.  This automatic conversion only applies if the input is a data frame in R which it is in the question.
library(sqldf)
DF <- data.frame(d = as.Date("2000-01-01") + 0:3)

sqldf("select max(d) as d from DF")
##            d
## 1 2000-01-04

dbDisconnect()

3) SQLite does not have a native date type which makes date processing with it somewhat onerous.  Just about every other SQL database does have date types.  duckdb is fairly close to SQLite and, like SQLite, is included in the duckdb R package so there is nothing additional to install, so if you have the choice try using that.
library(duckdb)

DF <- data.frame(d = as.Date("2000-01-01") + 0:3)

con <- dbConnect(duckdb())
dbWriteTable(con, "DF", DF)

dbGetQuery(con, "select max(d) as maxd from DF")
##         maxd
## 1 2000-01-04

dbDisconnect(con)

The H2 database is another one that comes included in the R driver package (RH2) but you will need to have java installed (although java has an automated installer so it is really easy to install).  Also H2 is supported by sqldf like SQLite.
library(sqldf)
library(RH2)  # sqldf will automatically use RH2 if loaded

sqldf("select max(d) maxd from DF")
##         maxd
## 1 2000-01-04

dbDisconnect()

